# jQuery или Javascript mp3-плеер

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Главное чтобы в нем был настраиваемый функционал и он поддавался верстке.
Если кто сталкивался уже с таким , может поделиться или дать ссылку ? 
Самое главное чтобы его можно было переверстать .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда то постил ответ с сылкой на [Jplayer](http://jplayer.org), посмотрите.

Comment: Видел его уже , думал есть что то подобное. Убедился что без Jplayer никак.